# REGEX to match all spaces in string except for spaces in between two string patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out a REGEX to match all spaces in a string except if the space is in between `<name>` and `</name>`.

For example, for the pattern:

```
aa11 b2 <name>CC-33 DD EE</name> FF
```

It would match with 3 spaces but ignore the ones between CC-33 and DD and between DD and EE.

Very new with REGEX, so far I have been able to come up with one that does the exact opposite of what I am looking for:

```
<name>.+?<\/name>|\S
```

**Edit:** The end goal is to split the string in Python by the matched spaces.

Comment: One way is to do that with a capture group which you would keep after a replacement `(<name>.*?</name>)|[^\S\n]+` https://regex101.com/r/iJl6QT/1 What is your goal?

Comment: See this Python demo https://ideone.com/4IchCl

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for what I am trying to do. The end goal is to split the string in Python by the matched spaces.

Comment: Like this? https://ideone.com/BA0qEL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `|\S` you can use `|[^\S\n]+` to match 1 or more spaces without newlines.

Then append a capture group to the first part of the alternation to keep that part.

Note that you don't have to escape the `\/`

```
(<name>.*?</name>)|[^\S\n]+
```

Then you can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and filter out the None's and empty strings:

```
import re

s = "aa11 b2 <name>CC-33 DD EE</name> FF"
pattern = r"(<name>.*?</name>)|[^\S\n]+"

print([s for s in re.split(pattern, s) if s])
```

Output

```
['aa11', 'b2', '<name>CC-33 DD EE</name>', 'FF']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BA0qEL) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJl6QT/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing split altogether.

```
(?m)(?:(?<=[ ])|^)(?:<name>(?:(?!</name>)[\S\s])*?</name>|[^ \r\n]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TvzpZP/1

Overview

```
(?m)
(?:
   (?<= [ ] )
 | ^ 
)
(?:
   <name>
   (?:
      (?! </name> )
      [\S\s] 
   )*?
   </name>
 | [^ \r\n]+ 
)
```